# Shared projects across repositories

Tags: architecture, tfs

I am struggling with an issue where my company is attempting to white label it's solution. We have a Solution A, inside Repository A like this

```
Repository A
      Solution A
          Project A
          Project B
          Project C
          Project D
          Project E (not shared and dependent on project A/B/C/D)
```

We wish to share a number of projects from Solution A into another Solution B which exists in Repository B. For example

```
Repository B
      Solution B
          Project A (From Solution A and Repository A)
          Project B (From Solution A and Repository A)
          Project C (From Solution A and Repository A)
          Project D (From Solution A and Repository A)
          Project F (not shared and dependent on project A/B/C/D)
```

This way when any of the Project A/B/C or D are updated and committed, then the Solution B will just need to be updated and Projects A/B/C and D will be updated from Repository A. Project F will then be built against the new version of Project A/B/C and D.

Is this even possible with TFS?

Please note we require the actual projects in the solutions not the assemblies. This is for debugging purposes.

Comment: You do not need the actual projects for debugging purposes if you publish the symbols and index the sources. The debugger will be able to find the actual source files from the build server. See [Index and publish symbol data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190722.aspx).

Comment: Also, which version of TFS are you talking about, and what do you mean by "repository"? TFS Version Control doesn't use the term "repository", though git is supported, and of course _does_ use that term. Which do you mean?

Comment: Yes I suggested using myget.org for nuget packages + symbols, and yes you are correct I shouldn't have used the term repository

Comment: So, which version of TFS?

Comment: We are using the cloud based version of TFS

Answer (score 1):

This is possible! But you know Nuget.org? I think Nuget is the best solution for your case.
In this presentation Scott Hanselman shows how use NuGet as Enteprise solution: [NuGet for the Enterprise: NuGet in a Continuous Integration Automated Build System](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetForTheEnterpriseNuGetInAContinuousIntegrationAutomatedBuildSystem.aspx)

Comment: I have also recommended Nuget but that was also denied.

Comment: Nuget not on site Nuget.org, but a internal Nuget, just sharing in the company... Is what you recommended?

Comment: I actually recommended using "myget.org"

Answer (score 0):

Considering only the following clear requirement

> Please note we require the actual projects in the solutions not the
>   assemblies.

You could just keep one solution - with project E, F, ..., N being the white labeled applications.

Like such:

```
Repository A
      Solution A
          Project Library A
          Project Library B
          Project Library C
          Project Library D
          Project Whitelabel E
          Project Whitelabel F
          Project Whitelabel N
```

Comment: I have suggested this approach, however that was rejected by the dev manager.